# JavaScript offset/pagination issue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, pagination

I am calling to my local API and trying to do it in a `pagination` style. I have `n` pictures that I want divided over `n / 4` rows (4 pictures per row).
So therefor, I am calling to my API, `images/count,offset`. But somehow I keep on getting the same results in `console.log`, namely the first four images.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var offset = 0;
    var timesToRun = $('.container').data('rows');
    var images = [];

    for(var i = 1; i <= timesToRun; i++) {

        $.ajax('http://192.168.10.11/images/4,' + offset, {

            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            },

            method: 'GET',

            success: function(data) {
                console.log('http://192.168.10.11/images/4,' + offset);
                offset = offset + 4;

                var currentSet = [];
                currentSet.push(data);

                console.log(currentSet);
            }

        });

    }

});
```

In Laravel I am pulling the number of images like so:

```
public function selectWithOffset($count, $offset)
    {
        $selectionOfImages = \DB::table('images')->skip($offset)->take($count)->get();
        return response()->json($selectionOfImages);
    }
```

[image: Current console output]

When I click the links I do receive the expected response.
What might go wrong here?

Comment: What does your route look like?

Comment: `Route::get('/images/{count},{offset}', 'ImageController@selectWithOffset');`

Comment: Start by dumping the values passed to your controller - you'll know if it's something with controller logic or witn sending/parsing route parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is within your JavaScript. `$.ajax` is asynchronous by default. 
The for loop will complete before any success callback of $.ajax is called, and this is the place where you increase the offset.

You have to options to fix this:

**1. Make $.ajax synchronous**

Add `async: false` to the $.ajax options.

```
$.ajax('http://192.168.10.11/images/4,' + offset, {
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    },
    async: false,
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

**2. Increment `offset` outside of the success callback**

```
for(var i = 1; i <= timesToRun; i++) {

    $.ajax('http://192.168.10.11/images/4,' + offset, {
        // ...
    });

    // Increment offset
    offset += 4;

}
```